# Laravel 5.4 Validation - required_if validation inside Array based on 2 fields found inside the array and outside

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How do we validate a field inside an array as required only if it meets 2 criterias?

I have a sample data below, and i want to validate a the end field ONLY IF **candidate_type** is 2 or 3 AND **is_present_company** is zero.

```
Array
(
    [candidate_type] => 3,
    [experience] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [job_title] => 'test title'
            [company] => 'test company'
            [start] => 'test start'
            [end] => 'test end'
            [is_present_company] => 1
            [location_country] => 
        )
    )
)
```

this is my Laravel validate code:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
  'experience.*.job_title' => 'required_if:candidate_type,1,2',
  'experience.*.company' => 'required_if:candidate_type,1,2',
  'experience.*.start' => 'required_if:candidate_type,1,2|date',
  'experience.*.end' => 'required_if:candidate_type,1,2|date',
  'experience.*.location_country' => 'required_if:candidate_type,1,2',
]);
```

to address this issue, I validated the array fields separately instead.

```
$hasExperienceError = false;
if (!empty($data['candidate_type']) && in_array($data['candidate_type'], [1, 2])) {
  if (empty($data['experience']) || count($data['experience']) < 1) {
    // $validator->errors()->add('experience', 'Please provide at least one experience');
  } else {

    foreach($data['experience'] as $key => $z) {

      $xv = Validator::make($z, [
        'job_title' => 'required',
        'company' => 'required',
        'start' => 'required|date',
        'end' => 'required_if:is_present_company,1|date',
        'location_country' => 'required',
      ]);
      if ($xv->fails()) {
        $hasExperienceError = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot a validate an array if the required condition is inside itself. You need to extract the field needed outside the array and use it as a required condition for the array.

Comment: hi @sandeesh.  thanks for the input.  i quess this would be the more practical way.  i followed your advise and "manually" had the array validated.

Answer (score 0):

Note: In code below 
project_type.*  is used to validates array

$validate_response = Validator::make($data, array(
                            'project_type.*' => 'required',
                                )
                );

```
if ($validate_response->fails()) {
return redirect($request->url())->withErrors($validate_response)->withInput();
} else {
}
```